# Power Query - get previous date per each category using M

Tags: powerquery

Say I have a table listing categories and dates, there are multiple dates per category, for example:

```
Cat | Date
A   | 1-Jan
A   | 2-Jan
A   | 3-Jan
B   | 1-Feb
B   | 2-Feb
```

I would like to add a column with the previous date based on the category, so the desired output would be:

```
Cat | Date  | Prev
A   | 1-Jan | null 
A   | 2-Jan | 1-Jan
A   | 3-Jan | 2-Jan
B   | 1-Feb | null
B   | 2-Feb | 2-Feb
```

I can do it reasonably simply by creating two index columns, one starting with 0 and the other starting with 1, merging the table with itself adding two new columns Cat and Date and using and IF statement to get what I need.

It works but it looks very clunky and inelegant.

What would be a "proper" and more elegant way of doing it using only M without any manual steps?

Comment: If `without any manual steps` means using only the UI and not the `Advanced Editor`, then you are probably stuck with clunky. BTW, your last `Prev` for group B is incorrect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't mind using the Advanced Editor, here is some code which

- Groups by Cat
- Aggregates by merely adding a "shifted column" to the original subtable

  - By shifting you:

    - add a *null* at the beginning
    - Remove the last entry

```
let

//change next line to reflect actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table30"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Cat", type text}, {"Date", type date}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Cat"}, {
    
        {"Prev Date", (t)=>
            Table.FromColumns(
                Table.ToColumns(t) & {{null} & List.RemoveLastN(t[Date],1)},
                {"Cat","Date","Prev"}
        ), type table[Cat=nullable text, Date=nullable date, Prev=nullable date]}}),
    
    #"Expanded Prev Date" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Prev Date", {"Date", "Prev"})
in
    #"Expanded Prev Date"
```

If your original dates are not sorted, then you can add a sort in Aggregation:

```
let

//change next line to reflect actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table30"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Cat", type text}, {"Date", type date}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Cat"}, {
    
        {"Prev Date", (t)=> 
            let 
                sortDates = Table.Sort(t, {"Date", Order.Ascending})
            in Table.FromColumns(
                Table.ToColumns(sortDates) & {{null} & List.RemoveLastN(sortDates[Date],1)},
                {"Cat","Date","Prev"}
        ), type table[Cat=nullable text, Date=nullable date, Prev=nullable date]}}),
    
    #"Expanded Prev Date" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Prev Date", {"Date", "Prev"})
in
    #"Expanded Prev Date"
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

That might work until the data is unsorted, etc.  This is the normal way to do it

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Cat", type text}, {"Date", type date}}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Cat"}, {{"data", each 
    let #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Table.Sort(_,{{"Date", Order.Ascending}}), "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type)
    in Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "PrevDate",  each try #"Added Index"{[Index]-1}[Date] otherwise null)
   , type table [Date=nullable date,PrevDate = nullable date]}}),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", {"Date", "PrevDate"}, {"Date", "PrevDate"})
in  #"Expanded data"
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is my two cents without grouping:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    Step1 = let c1=Table.Column(Source, "Cat") in List.Transform(List.Numbers(0,List.Count(c1)), each if _=List.PositionOf(c1,c1{_}) then null else Table.Column(Source, "Date"){_-1}),
    Step2 = Table.FromColumns(Table.ToColumns(Source) & {Step1},Table.ColumnNames(Source)&{"Prev"}),
    Step3 = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Step2,{{"Cat", type text}, {"Date", type date}, {"Prev", type date}})
in
    Step3
```

[image]

**NOTE**: The preceding date for the 2nd occurence of the 'B'-categorie should be the 1st of februari right?

---